# Webpack changing module id

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack for my webapp, part of the code (api code) is stored in `./src/config/api`
This folder is published as an npm package called `@myorg/api` and I'm using it as such in other projects:

`import * from '@myorg/api';`

All those projects are injected into the same page where I have a `shared.js` chunk
ALWAYS loaded first and I'd like to load this api code only once.

My problem is that webpack creates the following for my webapp:

`var api_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! @myorg/api */ "./src/config/api/index.js");`

But the projects using it has:
`var api_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! @myorg/api */ "./node_modules/@myorg/config/api/index.js");`

So since the key is different webpack is not finding the module from my `shared.js` chunk:

```
bootstrap:779 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:779)
    at fn (bootstrap:147)
    ...
```

Any idea how I can match those ids?
Each project is using it's own webpack config and the module is installed as an npm package (expect for the webapp where it's part of the code).

Answer (score 1):

This has been working for me:

```js
export const mapModuleIds = fn => compiler => {
  const context = compiler.options.context;

  compiler.hooks.compilation.tap("ChangeModuleIdsPlugin", compilation => {
    compilation.hooks.beforeModuleIds.tap("ChangeModuleIdsPlugin", modules => {
      const chunkGraph = compilation.chunkGraph
      for(const module of modules)
        if(module.libIdent){
          const origId = module.libIdent({ context })
          if(!origId) continue;
          chunkGraph.setModuleId(module, fn(origId, module))
        }
    })
  })
}
```

Then add it as a plugin like so:

```js
const webpackOptions = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    mapModuleIds(id => /* transform the id */),
    // ...
  ]
  // ...
}
```